# Can linked server providers be installed on a SQL Azure Database instance?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

Is it possible to install drivers on a SQL Azure Database instance (i.e, on the underlying host OS) so that linked servers with particular providers can be installed?

(I am assuming the creation of linked servers on a SQL Azure Database instance is possible).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NO. You can install nothing on Windows Azure SQL Database (WASD) Instance.

And the only "linked server" option for WASD, is when you add WASD as a linked server to your local SQL Server.

You can read more on recent updates to WASD [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2012/09/19/announcing-updates-to-windows-azure-sql-database.aspx).