# LinqPad connect two azure databases on same server

Tags: c#, azure-sql-database, linqpad

Per the FAQ (1), I can add additional databases to my existing connection in a number of ways.  I have tried them all, and none work for SQL Azure.

In fact, SQL Azure as a provider, doesn't even include the option to "Include additional databases."

Can someone please tell me a workaround for LinqPad to connect two databases?  I am trying to create a migration linqpad script to sync data from one database to another.

1. http://www.linqpad.net/FAQ.aspx#cross-database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This fails because SQL Azure does not let you create linked servers. See
[Can linked server providers be installed on a SQL Azure Database instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12978290/can-linked-server-providers-be-installed-on-a-sql-azure-database-instance)

If you simply want to copy data from one database to another, and the schemas are the same, a workaround is to create a separate connection using the same TypedDataContext class:

```
void Main()
{
    CopyFrom<Customer>("<source connection string>");
}

void CopyFrom<TTable> (string sourceCxString) where TTable : class
{
    // Create another typed data context for the source. Note that it must have compatible schema:
    using (var sourceContext = new TypedDataContext (sourceCxString) { ObjectTrackingEnabled = false })
    {
        // Delete the rows currently in our table:
        ExecuteCommand ("delete " + Mapping.GetTable (typeof (TTable)).TableName);

        // Insert the rows from the source table into the target table and submit changes:
        GetTable<TTable>().InsertAllOnSubmit (sourceContext.GetTable<TTable>());
        SubmitChanges();
    }
}
```

Simple Select Example:

```
void Main()
{
    SimpleSelect("<your conn string>");
}

void SimpleSelect (string sourceCxString)
{
    // Create another typed data context for the source. Note that it must have compatible schema:
    using (var sourceContext = new TypedDataContext (sourceCxString) { ObjectTrackingEnabled = false })
    {
        sourceContext.Assignee.OrderByDescending(a => a.CreateTimeStamp).Take(10).Dump();
        Assignee.OrderByDescending(a => a.CreateTimeStamp).Take(10).Dump();
    }
}
```

Comment: *Cannot execute text selection: The type or namespace name 'TypedDataContext' could not be found (press F4 to add a using directive or assembly reference)* Do you know what namespace this is under?  Seems I am missing a reference.

Comment: Note:  I have also tried `var ctx = new MyActualDatabaseName("...")` thinking perhaps that's what you meant.

Comment: You need to set a connection for that query. Set it to the database that you wish to copy data into.

Comment: Couldn't really get the copy to work, but updated with an example of a simple select.  Based on that, I should be able to go further.  Thanks.

Comment: Joe, how do you do it if the schemas don't match?  I am trying to connect two databases but it seems to think they share the same schema, which they do not, so it's throwing a SQL exception, "Invalid column name."